# Reopen Tcp socket on the same port

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a socket that serves a single request-response purpose.

I set it up on port XXX let it wait for a connection, read the data and reply with some data.

I would like to open a new socket on the same port. As soon as the response was sent.

That is handled externally (there is a manager that is checking the state of the thread and if it was used it disposes it and creates a new one.

The problem is that it gets blocked on

```
_socket = _socket.Accept();
```

and when a new client tries to connect it never leaves this line. (And client gets no reply).

The socket is running in

```
new Thread(Run);
```

and here is my Run method:

```
private void Run()
{
    var ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);
    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        _socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        _socket.Listen(100);
        _socket = _socket.Accept();
        var data = string.Empty;
        while (true)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[1024];
            var bytesRec = _socket.Receive(bytes);
            data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
            if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) <= -1) continue;
            var dataWithoutEof = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal));
            //TODO: do smt with the data
            break;
        }
        var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testResponse" + "<EOF>");
        _socket.Send(byteData);

        _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        _socket.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I suppose that I am not closing the existing socket correctly.

Comment: Can you show the code containing the new thread call?

Comment: Correct you are overwriting the listening socket and only closing the servicing socket.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there is one "Accepting socket" that is bound to the specific port. Every time a client establishes a connection a new "servicing" socket is created and the reading/writing/closing of this socket is specific to each client (so I can have multiple servicing sockets for 1 Accepting socket. If I close the accepting socket it will not close my servicing sockets but I will simply stop accepting new connections. Is that correct?

Comment: It's probably not blocked on Listen but on Accept.

Comment: @VojtechB correct assuming that you are running single threaded. It is possible to handle multiple connections if you start a thread for each client, or you have to make use of select.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is wrong you should not expect this method to exit because you want your server up and running the whole time. I am assuming here you call run several times. Don't do that.
The code becomes then something like this :

```
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
_socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
_socket.Listen(100);
while (true)
{
    var _servicingsocket = _socket.Accept();
    ....
    _servicingsocket.close();
}
```

accept is a blocking call. That waits for a new connection.
_socket is a listening socket and must be kept during the lifetime of the server.

A TCP connection is based on the notion of a socket pair.
When the server starts you have a single socket that listens on port 100.
Suppose a connection is established, then accept returns what is called a servicing socket that is basically a clone from the listening socket. This means that it is also using source port 100, but because it is a servicing socket it belongs to a socket pair that identifies the connection. A socket pair is the combination of 2 sockets, your own socket and the peer. When a data comes in, TCP will iterate through the socket pairs to find the right socket.

An additional advantage of doing it this way is that you allow other connection attempts to queue up on the listening socket while you are processing the first request. Your _socket is overwritten with the servicing socket and you are then assuming that the listening socket is going to be garbage collected. I am not sure if this is going to happen because I haven't tried it like you are doing it in your code because it is a bad idea in the first place because it implements idisposable. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) If you really want to close the server you have to make sure to close both the servicing socket and the listening socket to make the code clean.

Comment: Thank you, this pattern is exactly what I needed. I have a few additional questions if you dont mind: 1) If I invoke 2 calls from a different clients - would they be able to connect to the same port? Will their requests be queued? or one will be refused? 2) Is it a good practice to open a new port for each client?

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. listen allows to specify how many clients are queued.